# div contain table not scrolling properly

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make a div scrollable (this div have a table inside) and is inside another div (this div have height: 100%). This little image show the result i need.

This is the code im using but if you can see in the image the scroll is not showing.

[image]

```css
#main-aside
    {
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
    }
    
    .table-search {
           margin:0 auto;
     width: 440px;
        height: 41px;
     padding: 3px 4px 1px 4px;
     background: #212020;
     border-bottom: #000 1px solid;
    }
    
    #listEmployeeTable { // this is the div that contains the table, not working now
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    
    .employee-table-column table{
        width: 440px; // table have a width specified
    }
```

```html
    <aside id="main-aside" class="x-east">
          
          <div class="table-search">
      
            <label>Search by name</label>
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchEmployeList">
            </div>
         
          </div>
          
          <div id="listEmployeeTable" class="employee-table-column">
            <table class="table-striped employee-data-table">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th class="name">Name</th>
                        <th class="time">Time</th>
                        <th class="action">Action</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td>NAME 1</td>
                        <td class="Time">04/12/2015 03:04 AM</td>
                        <td class="Action">Start after left</td>
                     </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
          </div>
        </aside>
```

Currently this is how it looks

[image]

Comment: Any possibility to reproduce in JSFiddle?

Comment: I will try to make a fiddle but basically is make the div that contains the table get a scrollbar-y